# Calculating Average with Sentinel Value

Tags: java

So I have a sentinel value of -1 and it should kick me out of the program when I enter that value.

The problem I have is that value is included when I calculate the average and I don't want that.

Example of what happens: `( 8+ 5 + 3 + -1 / 4)`
What I'd like to happen: `(8 + 5 + 3 / 3)`

```
do {
    grade = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a grade:"));
    sum = sum + grade;
    count = count + 1;

} while (grade != SENTINEL);
avg = sum/count;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,String.format("%.1f",avg));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your logic slightly:

```
do {
    grade = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a grade:"));
    if (grade == SENTINEL) {
        break;                  // exit the loop upon hitting the SENTINEL value
    }

    sum = sum + grade;          // only increase the sum for positive values
    count = count + 1;
} while (true);

avg = sum/count;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,String.format("%.1f",avg));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to resolve the issue would be to wrap the 2 lines after the input in an if statement. A more proper way would be to break the loop as Tim indicated, to avoid performing the value comparison twice.

```
do{....
    if(grade != SENTINEL)
    {
        sum = sum + grade;
        count = count + 1;
    }
}while...
```